# Renormalization with a relation between parameters

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

Let's take a theory with three parameters $(m_0, \mu, \lambda, g)$ and three particles with mass $m_0 = 0$, $m_1 = 2\mu^2$ and $m_2 = g v$, where
$$ v = \frac{\sqrt{\lambda}}{\mu} $$
To renormalize the theory with fixed $v$ means, for example, that $\mu = v \lambda$ is no more a parameter of the theory. The mass $m_1$ is consequently shifted from it's previous value $m_1 = 2\mu^2$ and become an independent parameter. The parameters of the theory are:
$$(m_0, m_1, \lambda, g)$$
Now, fix the renormalization condition such that $g$ doesn't gain radiative contribution:
$$ \Gamma(\tilde P) = -ig$$
Where $\tilde P$ is a chosen condition in momentum space (for example zero momentum transfer).

**Question**: Does $m_2$ gain radiative corrections? The answer should be "Yes", but I cannot find out why.

**Edit**: The lagrangian is the following: 
$$ \mathcal{L} = \frac 12 (\partial_{\mu}\sigma)^2 - \frac 12 (2\mu^2) \sigma^2 + \frac 12 (\partial_{\mu} \pi)^2 + \bar \psi (i \gamma^{\mu} \partial_{\mu} - gv) \psi + \mathcal L_{I}  $$
$$ \mathcal L_I = - \lambda v \sigma^3 - \lambda v \sigma \pi^2 - \frac{\lambda}{2} \sigma^2 \pi^2 - \frac{\lambda}{4} \sigma^4 - \frac{\lambda}{4}\pi^4 - g \bar \psi (\sigma + i \gamma^5 \pi ) \psi$$